# combining deep nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed best with following XML example : What I have is the following :

```
<Story>
<Content para="div"><local>This is some (normal) text to start with.</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>Connect something (</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58236"/></local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>) to something else (</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58237"/></local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>), and make sure it's connected to this (</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58239"/></local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>).</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>If that's ok do the same with this (</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58238"/></local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>) also.</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>This is some normal text.</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>This also.</local></Content>
</Story>
```

and the output I'd like to get is as follows :

```
<Story>
<Content para="div"><local>This is some (normal) text to start with.</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>Connect something (<refnr value="58236"/>) to something else (<refnr value="58237"/>), and make sure it's connected to this (<refnr value="58239"/>).</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>If that's ok do the same with this (<refnr value="58238"/>) also.</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>This is some normal text.</local></Content>
<Content para="div"><local>This also.</local></Content>
</Story>
```

Or, to 'code' it : Any [Content para=div][local] node ending with an open bracket, needs to be merged with the following [Content para=div][local] nodes untill the node containing the last closing bracket and the end of the sentence (identified by closing dot). I was able to do some things, but it became overly complex and slow and without all wanted results. Any advice using xslt2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation** (can easily be translated to XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Story>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Content[1]/local"/>
  </Story>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Content/local[not(ends-with(., '('))]">
  <Content para="div"><local><xsl:apply-templates/></local></Content>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::Content[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Content/local[ends-with(., '(')]">
  <Content para="div"><local><xsl:apply-templates/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select="../following-sibling::Content[1]"/>
  </local></Content>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "../following-sibling::Content
             [local[starts-with(.,')') and ends-with(.,'.')]][1]
               /following-sibling::Content[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Content/local" mode="inGroup">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"
         select="../following-sibling::Content[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="inGroup" match="Content/local[starts-with(.,')') and ends-with(.,'.')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="refnr"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Story>
 <Content para="div"><local>This is some (normal) text to start with.</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>Connect something (</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58236"/></local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>) to something else (</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58237"/></local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>), and make sure it's connected to this (</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58239"/></local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>).</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>If that's ok do the same with this (</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local><refnr value="58238"/></local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>) also.</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>This is some normal text.</local></Content>
 <Content para="div"><local>This also.</local></Content>
</Story>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Story>
   <Content para="div">
      <local>This is some (normal) text to start with.</local>
   </Content>
   <Content para="div">
      <local>Connect something (<refnr value="58236"/>) to something else (<refnr value="58237"/>), and make sure it's connected to this (<refnr value="58239"/>).</local>
   </Content>
   <Content para="div">
      <local>If that's ok do the same with this (<refnr value="58238"/>) also.</local>
   </Content>
   <Content para="div">
      <local>This is some normal text.</local>
   </Content>
   <Content para="div">
      <local>This also.</local>
   </Content>
</Story
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to nest two approaches:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Story">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Content" group-adjacent="contains(., '(') or contains(., ')') or boolean(self::Content[local[refnr]])">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="Content[local[ends-with(., '.')]]">
            <Content para="div">
              <local>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/local/node()"/>
              </local>
            </Content>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With that stylesheet and your sample input I get the result you posted. I am not sure however whether the conditions I used are too simple for the real input, report back whether there can be "normal" text containing `refnr` elements for instance.

[edit]
With a `matches` as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Story">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Content" 
      group-adjacent="not(matches(., '\(.*\)')) 
                       or boolean(self::Content[local[refnr]])">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="Content[local[ends-with(., '.')]]">
            <Content para="div">
              <local>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/local/node()"/>
              </local>
            </Content>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the edited input sample is transformed as required I think. Of course once you would have e.g. `<Content para="div"><local>Connect (foo) something (</local></Content>` that approach is also too simple.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for this already, I'll play around with it to see if it works in real live with more complex content. There are no refnr in 'normal' text, but normal text might contain bracketted text like [local]This is some (very) normal text[/local], not too sure what's gonna happen then but I'm going to check //edit// : i've tested and if normal text contains brackets the result is indeed unwanted

Comment: I changed the `contains` checks to a regular expression, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks again Martin, but this time the 2 last nodes are also merged it seems.